# Why two energies look same in the relativistic normalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, quantum-states, normalization

I'm reading Peskin's QFT textbook.

In this book, to make normalization of momentum eigenstate Lorentz invariant, we define momentum eigenket as
$$\left| \mathbf{p} \right> = \sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}} a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> $$
where $a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger}$ is creation operator.

Then, inner product of two momentum eigenkets corresponding to different(or maybe the same) momenta should be
$$\left< \mathbf{p} | \mathbf{q} \right> = 2\sqrt{E_{\mathbf{p}}E_{\mathbf{q}}} (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q})$$
Here, $(2\pi)^3$ comes from commutation realtion of creation & annihilation operator. But the book says that not $\sqrt{E_{\mathbf{p}}E_{\mathbf{q}}}$ but $E_{\mathbf{p}}$ is right.

Am I doing wrong or there is something that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're both right. $E_\mathbf{p} = \sqrt{p^2 + m^2}$, and similarly for $q$. The delta function means that, for factors that multiply it, $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ are interchangeable. That is:
$$\sqrt{E_\mathbf{p}E_\mathbf{q}}\delta(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}) = E_\mathbf{p}\delta(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}) = E_\mathbf{q}\delta(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q}).$$

Comment: Paraphrasing your answer, because of sampling property of Dirac delta function, are above three expressions all valid?

Comment: Yes, that is another way to say it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.